# django use multiple widgets in form field

Tags: django

I'm trying to use two widgets (one to add custom class names, one for the choices) in one field, but not sure how.. there's no clear way specified in the official documentation to do this

`widget=forms.TextInput(attrs={'class': 'select is-medium'})`

`widget=forms.Select`

Answer (score 1):

If you want a Select field with custom classes in it you just have to do the following:
`widget=forms.Select(attrs={'class': 'select is-medium'})`

In case you want to have two widgets in one field check [Django MultiWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#multiwidget).