# How to display a custom form with multiple widgets for a field in Django admin?

Tags: django, django-admin

The Django docs [say](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/contrib/admin/#adding-custom-validation-to-the-admin) you can add a form to the admin UI:

```
class ArticleAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    form = MyArticleAdminForm
```

I want a custom editing UI for a special field in my model, where I display multiple widgets.  (It's not exactly the same, but an analogy might be an old-school hex editor widget, where you want fine editing control on a big blob of information.)  Perhaps I could break the multiple values into multiple database objects and use an InlineAdmin, but I have app-specific reasons to not do that.

I thought I'd use a `Form` object with some custom fields, but Django says it must be a `ModelForm`:

```
<class 'myapp.admin.MyAdmin'>: (admin.E016) The value of 'form' must inherit from 'BaseModelForm'.
```

Is it possible to display multiple widgets (basically a very custom form) for a single model value in Django admin?

**EDIT**: It looks like [MultiWidget](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/forms/widgets/#multiwidget) might work?  I'm gonna look into that.  Also, [this question is related](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67579161/django-use-multiple-widgets-in-form-field).  That suggests I should just change the widget on the field.

Answer (score 0):

The answer was to make a [`MultiWidget`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/4.1/ref/forms/widgets/#multiwidget), overriding:

- `__init__` to set up the widgets
- `decompress` and `value_from_datadict` to unpack and pack the field value
- `template_name` to render my own template
- `get_context` to make the context for the template